# osmdroid path not drawn

Tags: android, path, drawing, osmdroid

I want to draw a path with osmdroid:

```
myPath = new PathOverlay(Color.RED, this);
for(int i=0;i<strecke.size();i++)
    myPath.addPoint(new GeoPoint(track.get(i).lat, track.get(i).lon));
map.getOverlays().add(myPath);
```

The path is drawn correctly on a certain zoom level. When zooming in the path sometimes is not drawn at all. But if a certain point lies in the visible area the path is drawn correctly. This point is not the first or last point I have added so I don't have a clue what the problem is.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long standing issue with the PathOverlay. Please see issue [Issue 392](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=392). There is a quick fix in there, but the short of it is that the PathOverlay needs a rewrite. The other option is to write your own Overlay and do the path drawing yourself. If you want to support high zoom levels without drawing distortions then you should use a `SafeDrawingOverlay` and a `SafeTranslatedPath`. Check the javadoc for usage instructions.